# Requests library return HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I test webscraping on localhost using requests library to open and get website content. When I test on my localhost some website it's work perfectly.

But the same script, the same tested URL on producetion server return:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /somewhere.html (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

Anybody know what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: (See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=ssl#ssl-cert-verification) for more)

```
requests.get('your_url_here', verify=False)
```